# Normal matrix eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Been trying to do this question for a while but not getting anywhere:

Given $A$ normal, and $Ax=tx$ (i.e $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $t$), show that $(A^*)x=t^*x$ where $A^*$ is the hermitian conjugate of $A$ and $t^*$ is the complex conjugate of $t$.

I keep finding myself needing that the dimension of the eigenspace of $t$ is equal to $1$, which of course isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality  $A^\ast x$ and $x$. Recall that the equality holds only if the two vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: @AlanMuniz Okay, thank you, that tells us that $A^*$ has eigenvector $x$, and that the eigenvalue has the same modulus as $t$, but how do we then show the eigenvalue is $t^*$?

Comment: Use the inner product. $a\|x\|^2 = <A^\ast x, x> = <x,Ax> = <x, tx> = \bar{t}\|x\|^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the fact that $A$ is normal, show that
$$
\|(A - t I)x\| = \|(A - tI)^*x\|.
$$